# Extract text from a variable

Tags: linux, bash

In a bash script I have a variable fete which contains

```
{"feastedsaint": "eline,Helena,Helene,Heliena,Laetitia,Lena,Lenaic,Nelly"}
```

and I would like to get in another variable this text

```
eline,Helena,Helene,Heliena,Laetitia,Lena,Lenaic,Nelly
```

How can I do it with Linux / bash commands?

Comment: Your original variable looks a lot like JSON, so you could use [jq.](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 1):

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```
var='{"feastedsaint": "eline,Helena,Helene,Heliena,Laetitia,Lena,Lenaic,Nelly"}'
names=$(jq -r .feastedsaint <<<"$var")
echo "$names"
```

```
eline,Helena,Helene,Heliena,Laetitia,Lena,Lenaic,Nelly
```

---

The [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) equivalent would be

```
names=$(jshon -e feastedsaint -u <<<"$var")
```

Comment: Nice clean answer. Do you know of a decent, intelligible guide or tutorial on `jq` please - I never manage to find anything satisfactory.

Comment: There is documentation available at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/, that's probably the best there is. I find jq very difficult to work with for anything complicated.

Comment: This tool (http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) looks like it's easier to work with, but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using external commands would be as easy as:

```
$var2 = $(echo ${var1}|cut -f4 -d\")
```

You can also do it without external commands using ${var%"} and ${var#"} (or %%/##)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `grep` and *"look-arounds"*:

```
newvar=$(echo "$fete" | grep -Po '(?<=: ").*(?="})')
```

or, slightly more simply:

```
newvar=$(grep -Po '(?<=: ").*(?="})') <<< "$fete")
```

where:

- -P means to use Perl regexes
- -o means to print only the matching part
- (?<=: ") means look behind for a colon followed by space and double quotes
- (?="}) means look ahead for double quotes and a closing brace